# Windows Lua to executable not find lua5.1.dll

Tags: windows, lua

I have a Lua program (written in Lua 5.1). I'm on Windows 7, trying to use srlua to convert a lua file into an executable. finally  i have create an executable used

`glue.exe srlua.exe myscript.lua gd.exe`

when i click exe/bat to execute. it crashed . tips : no find lua51.dll in computer.
when i used cmd to execute . it work. even i only move gd.exe to other dir.
so, why ? 
doesnot srlua create standalone exe without lua environment? 
[dir ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vguz.png)

[error tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKXoO.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, an executable will only look in a few places for the .dll (in order):

1) Any dependency paths will be searched first. These you can set when you are creating the project (generally through the IDE).

2) The current directory that the executable is running from. For example, if **gd.exe** was in the folder **myexe** in **C:** drive, the directory **C:\myexe** would be checked.

3) The system directory. For Windows, it's something along the lines of **C:\Windows\System32**.

4) Anything additional paths, specified by the **PATH** environment variable.

So, if you moved your executable **gd.exe** from **C:\myexe** to **C:\myexe2**, you would either need to point to the .dll via dependencies/the **PATH** environment variable, or move all of the .dll files that you need to the new directory.

If command line works to run the program, but not the .exe itself, your command line has the **PATH** environment variable set. You can set it in the command line using setx path "%path%;c:\newpath" or use the the Control Panel -> System and Security -> System then clicking on Advance System Settings -> Environment Variables and under System Variables, look for the **PATH** key word.

Keeping the .dll files and executable in the directory (**c:\myexe** for example) and running the executable is a good way to make sure they work together and that all required .dll files are seen by your executable.

Source (even though it doesn't mention the **PATH** environment variable): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @sgame Just remember to up-vote an answer or comment to gain more clarification or offer more clarification. Just leaving this unanswered or without additional information does not help the rest of the community.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Lua environments: your directory structure shows Lua51.dll, but your error message references Lua5.1.dll, which you don't have (and those are two different files). Somehow you depend on a module that was compiled against Lua5.1.dll. You can figure out the dependency chain by using [a dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) as it will show what DLLs are being loaded and from what locations. You can also run it in the "profile" mode, which will show where the error you see happens in the dependency chain, so you'll know what DLL or executable is at fault.